# how to read a string as a complex number?

Tags: r

I have a string which has a complex format, how can I use complex() to treat it as a complex number? For example:

```
myStr="0.76+0.41j"
```

now I want to do sth like:

```
myStr_complex=complex(myStr) # my question is how should I do this part?
```

Eventually

```
Im(myStr_complex)
```

should print

```
0.41
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

R prefers to use `i` rather than `j`. Aslo note that `complex` is different than `as.complex` and the latter is used for conversion. You can do

```
myStr <- "0.76+0.41j"
myStr_complex  <- as.complex(sub("j","i",myStr))
Im(myStr_complex)
# [1] 0.41
```